# Rendering of NavMenu.razor with .net8 as interactive

Tags: blazor, .net-8.0

I'm working on a project created from the VS template Blazor Web App, allowing both server/side-side rendering and interactivity per component. I also added the client project to be set as a PWA. I'm enjoying the flexibility to use InteractiveAutoRenderMode by default and the 2 others whenever there's a good reason for a particular one.
I now need to add some interactivity to NavMenu.razor to get expendable sub-menus.

```
            <NavLink class="nav-link" @onclick="()=>expandSubNav = !expandSubNav">
                <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Top
            </NavLink>
            @if (expandSubNav)
            {
                <NavLink class="expand-menu" href="">
                    <span>Sub1</span>
                </NavLink>
                <NavLink class="" href="">
                    <span>Sub2</span>
                </NavLink>
            }
[...]
@code {
    private bool expandSubNav;
}
```

I got no interactivity

I tried the variants

```
@rendermode @(new Interactive{WebAssembly/Auto/Server}RenderMode())
```

interactivity worked only with @rendermode @(new InteractiveServerRenderMode()), the other 2 giving
`Error: One or more errors occurred. (Root component type 'BlazorApp.Components.Layout.NavMenu' could not be found in the assembly 'BlazorApp')`

It could be noted that I can get InteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode to work --and InteractiveServerRenderMode to fail--, if I move Components\Layout\NavMenu.razor and \wwwroot\bootstrap* from the server project where the template put them to the client project (that's troubleshooting, doesn't sound like s sound idea)

I'm stuck thinking I've no option that's not a bad/terrible idea:

1. I use InteractiveServerRenderMode, which means a PWA gets it menu rendered on the server.....
2. I use InteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode, having to move Components\Layout\NavMenu.razor and \wwwroot\bootstrap* to the client project. In which case I'm essentially better off creating a standalone Webassembly (I see really no point having a few components rendering dynamically as auto if your menu won't load before the WASM DOM quicks in) which a handful of controllers, in other words I'm back to the asp.net core 3.1 days, and have to forget all the bells and whistles provided by .net8

I couldn't find useful documentation on the subject of the particular navmenu's interactivity. Are the expectations that it's always rendered server-side? Anything I'm sillingly missing here?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to place the NavMenu inside the Client project if you want to use it in wasm interactivity. All the parts that are supposed to work on client have to be in Client project.

Now it depends how your page is structured, if you would benefit from having SSR (for example you have pages like "home", "about", "contacts") or not. If your website is more like an app and you require the interactivity from the very start or you want PWA capabilities, you are better with standalone wasm app.

For this particular and simple example of hiding the menu I would recommend to use (sigh) javascript...

And in general: keeping as much as possible in SSR, use server interactivity where users understand the limitations and wasm where more interactivity is necessary. Also keeping the interactivity resolution on page level.

Answer (score 0):

Any component that you want to render in Client mode needs to be either in the Client project or a shared Razor Class Library.  I recommend using a Library that both projects can see.  You don't need to move anything in the *wwwroot* directory.

In the later part of the question your assertions are muddled.  If you want freedom to choose, it comes at a cost

*InteractiveAuto* with interactivity set at *Per Page/Component* is a minefield.  Looks wonderful on paper and a happy path demo.  Start to write a real App and things get complicated very quickly as you are discovering.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you guys for your answers and clarifications.
After some time trying to make it work as Auto I'm throwing the towel and will run it as InteractiveServerRenderMode.